# Normalize overuse of "precondition" endpoints in Collection and its folders & environments

Tags: collections, environment-variables, postman

I have been using Postman so much and built a lot of useful things in it, but now need to implement one more thing.
Briefly:

Need to create test cases to test a correct records counting for every institution.
Now I handled it like that

Structure:

---------**Collection**
-------**Folder**
---**Districts(folder)**

-some folders with tests

---**Colleges(folder)**

-some folders with tests

---**Schools(folder)**

**-Principal(Folder with test in Schools folder)**

where these requests:

1. **POST:** Create a list
   where in Tests:
   `var jList = JSON.parse(responseBody);
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("list_id", jList.data.id);`
2. **POST:** Add some filters to list
3. **GET:** `lists/{{list_id}}` whete in "Test" code:

```

```
var allLists = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    pm.test("test count", function () {
        const value = allLists.data.count;
        pm.expect(typeof value === 'number').to.eql(true);
        pm.expect(value > 0 && value < 999999).to.eql(true);
    }); // I check if the number(made in step№2 in a range we need
```

---

```

4. **DELETE:** delete this list

I guess I do 'overhead work' adding POST(create a list) and -DELETE endpoints in every folder, can I somehow bring it out to environment or variable and execute it before every **POST:** `Add some filters to list` and -DELETE endpoint after that
Something like general **BeforeEach** and **AfterEach**

Perhaps can I even bring this(below) out in one place for every separate test?

```
pm.test("test count", function () {
        const value = allLists.data.count;
        pm.expect(typeof value === 'number').to.eql(true);
        pm.expect(value > 0 && value < 999999).to.eql(true);
    });
```

[Here is an example how it looks like](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N80uqoN5czi_msgc8BjqB35WikrnLEqA) if it not difficult, give me a piece of advice! Thanks

Comment: We don't have permissions to view that file on the google drive link

Comment: In your first POST step you could just use `pm.environment.set("list_id", pm.response.json().data.id)` to set the variable. You seem to be mixing the older and newer syntax in your requests. Have you had a look at the collection/sub-folder elements? http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/13/keep-it-dry-with-collection-and-folder-elements/

Comment: thanks for the response, just download the collection and add to you postman, of course you can't see it in google)

Comment: You can’t download anything because it asks to submit a request to access it, can you check the sharing options on your link.

Comment: @DannyDainton, yeah, sorry, just have shared with you